# Netbeans telling me that a value is boolean when it is an int

Tags: java, netbeans

my while loop :

```
while (j =>0&& (courseArray[j].compareByCourse(value)) >=0 ){

}
```

is giving me this error in netbeans:  `int cannot be converted to boolean`

method:

```
public static void insertionSort(Course[] courseArray){

    Course value ;   // the next value from the unsorted list to be inserted into the sorted list
    int i;     // i is a pointer to an item in the unsorted list
    int j;    // j is a pointer to an item in the sorted list; originally the sorted list is just a[0]
    int compare;

    for (i=1; i<courseArray.length; i++){
         value = courseArray[i];    
         j = i -1;

         compare = courseArray[j].compareByCourse(value);

         while (j =>0&& (courseArray[j].compareByCourse(value)) >=0 ){

         }
    }
}
```

compareByCourse method:

```
//method to compare Courses by course name
int compareByCourse(Course other){
    return this.course.compareTo(other.getCourse());
}
```

`j` is an `int`, the return value is an `int`, `0` is an `int`, so where is the boolean?

Comment: What's `j =>0` supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have confused the operator `>=` with `=>` *(which is not a valid operator in Java)*. Try changing the while condition to:

```
while (j >= 0 && (courseArray[j].compareByCourse(value)) >= 0 )
```

Also if you are assigning `j` to:

```
compare = courseArray[j].compareByCourse(value);
```

use it in the while loop (you can also use it directly).

Comment: Uh, what is that `=>` operator to start with?

Comment: An explanation of what `=>` is would make this an _answer_.

Comment: Oh wow.  I feel stupid.  I meant to take the compare variable out.  I was using it to try and figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @devnull sorry, but is `=>` a valid operator in Java? I don't really know what it is.

Comment: @Christian I asked so because your answer seemed to indicate that it's _some_ operator.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that (not so good at English) I will clarify that.